# How to push all stored files in my laravel project to the github?

Tags: laravel, git

I have problem on pushing all stored images to my laravel project to the github I already try to use this following command.

1. Fetch all
2. Git add .
3. Git add *

but still the folder inside in the github still not updating, i try to research on this gitignore,
I dont think if that is the problem git ignore pushing the files to my respository

**My Laravel Project Folder**

[image: folder]

**Git repository folder:**

[image: my git repo]

Comment: can you post the contents if the `.gitignore` file

Comment: what do you mean post the content. do you mean the text inside of gitignore?

Comment: yes the text inside gitignore

Comment: this is the text inside of gitignore *
!.gitignore

Comment: The `*` in your `.gitignore` is saying to ignore all in that folder, while `!.gitignore` says not to ignore the `.gitignore` file itself. Remove `*`, if you really want to commit all the files in there.

Comment: so let say i remove that * how can i push all files to my repository, may virtual detect only the new changes or updates etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

That's happening because you defined that folder (or it was automatically defined) in your `.gitignore` file. This file lets Git know that it should ignore certain files and not track them, hence you can't add them to your repository. There are actually three solutions to this problem:

**Solution I:**

would be to remove `'storage/app/public'` folder from your `.gitignore` file.

**Solution II:**

could be to use [webpack](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix) to copy all the contents from storage folder to your public folder. Add something like this in your `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
mix.copyDirectory('storage/app/public' 'public/img');
```

Solution III: 
would be to create [storage link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk), which will virtually copy all the contents from your `storage/app/public` folder to `public/storage` folder. All you have to do is run this command in your console:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Hope that one of these solutions could help you out. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: question. what will happen to my uploaded images. those images will delete permanently? and those images can't use anymore?

Comment: Your uploaded images won't be deleted in any of these cases.